# How to programmatically search text in jar file?

Tags: java, search, jar

I want to search my sources.jar for the occurrence of a certain search token.

In Bash, this will extract the jar to a stream and grep for the string:

```
unzip -p sources.jar | grep $SEARCH_TOKEN
```

In Java, reading all entries via [JarInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarInputStream.html) looks rather tedious. Is there a better/simpler way (for both, the looping and the grepping)?

Comment: What kind of simpler way do you think of??? The JarInputStream is THE way to access JAR files for reading!

Comment: A simpler way like `new MagicLibIDidNotKnowYet(sources.jar).grep(token)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better/simpler way (for both, the looping and the grepping)?

In short, No (probably).

(I guess you might get lucky, and find an existing Java utility command someone has already written.  I don't rate your chances though.)

---

**UPDATE**

It is your lucky day!

http://metastatic.org/source/Jargrep.java

Note that the code is GPL 2.  Respect the license!